# How can I use a video header that's over 8MB?

Tags: plugins, uploads, videos, video-header

I'm using a theme that supports WordPress's (relatively new) video header feature. I want to upload a video that's over 8MB big, and I don't want to reduce the size of the video. How can I force it to accept a larger video? Is there a file that I can edit or a plugin that I can download?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to have such a heavy video header, as it will take long to load for end users. You can use a tool like http://www.videosmaller.com/ to compress it.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is enforced by [`_validate_header_video`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/_validate_header_video/) method, registered as validation callback on respective Customizer setting.

There is a filter that allows you to hook into the process and manipulate those arguments:

```
add_filter( 'customize_dynamic_setting_args', function ( $args, $id ) {

    if ( 'header_video' === $id ) {
        // change $args['validate_callback']
    }

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Do I just put this code into functions.php? I don't really understand how to use this.

Comment: Unfortunately you would probably have to rewrite that callback (make your own version of it) and replace original with it (using filter I've shown), since there is no easy way to just adjust the size check within it.

Answer (score 0):

check your **max_upload_size** in your "php.ini" file.

check more on this. [URL 1](https://www.bitcatcha.com/blog/2016/increase-maximum-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/), [URL 2](http://www.thecreatology.com/how-to-increase-upload-media-file-size-limit-in-wordpress.html),

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I don’t believe this is the issue the OP is up against, though it may indeed also be a part of the problem. @Rarst, has another major part of the solution, IMHO.

Comment: when I faced this issue, I tried this solution. That's why I suggested.

Comment: Not the issue in the question, out of the box video headers will restrict to 8MB even if you can upload larger file.